# i want to add vertical scrollbar to gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

i have bound data into a grid view in my asp.net application. i have inserted pagging into it but instead i want to add scroll bar to avoid long pagging.

This is my grid view code:

```
<div class="box-content" style="min-height: 170px">
<asp:GridView ID="gvVenFileQA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
EnableModelValidation="True"
ShowHeader="true" Width="100%" CssClass="altrowstable" AllowPaging="true" 
EmptyDataText="No Data Available !"
PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvVenFileQA_PageIndexChanging" 
OnRowDataBound="gvVenFileQA_RowDataBound"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVenFileQA_SelectedIndexChanged" 
DataKeyNames="ID,RUN_ID">
<Columns>
```

I don't want to add scrolling into the outer  tag but to the inside bound data. Please suggest

Comment: have you tried specifying max-height to that `box-content` div or the `GridView` control?

Comment: yes i did but it applies the scrollbar on the box instead of the data inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.box-content { max-height: 200px; overflow: scroll; }
```

Comment: on applying scrolling on the box content, the paging remains the same and there is no effect on the inside bound data

Comment: sorry its done thanks. i forgot to change paging to false .lol my bad. thanks alot